# Access to the path 'caminho' is denied. VS2017

Tags: c#, arquivo, visual-studio-2017

Estou a tentar criar um ficheiro e guardá-lo numa pasta criada por mim com o nome "*temporario*". Criei essa pasta no disco E:\, e dentro do meu programa, no disco C:. Usando File.Create(file), aparece o erro

> `Acess to the path 'E:\temporario' is denied.`

Ou, no caso da pasta no meu programa

> `Access to the path 'C:\Users\srodrigues\Documents\ProjetoPAP\ConversorPDFImage\Main\temporario' is denied.`

Já pesquisei um vário sites, em inglês e em português, e fala tudo sobre dar uncheck na opção "Só de leitura" da pasta e já fiz isso, em dar autorização ao meu utilizador de escrever na pasta e continuo com o mesmo erro.

O que posso fazer para conseguir guardar o ficheiro nessa pasta? Tenho preferência que guarde na pasta do programa.

**OBS:** estou a fazer manipulação de ficheiros PDF e, se usar o `document.Save(filepath)` do [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/), guarda em ambas as pastas sem algum problema, nunca tive problemas em guardar ficheiros na pasta `E:\temporario`, mas agora nem essa pasta está a dar para guardar o ficheiro.

EDIT: vou colocar aqui o meu código - agora completo (com a alteração proposta por Augusto Vasques):

```
    int indexi = 0;
    private void proc2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Procurar arquivos no computador";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"E:\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Imagens (.bmp,.jpg,.png,.tiff,.tif) |*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png;*tiff;*tif|Todos os arquivos (*.*)|*.*";
        DialogResult resposta = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (resposta == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                string caminhoCompleto = file;
                caminho2 = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
                caminhotb2.Text = caminhoCompleto;
                string fish = "";
                string path = @"E:\\temporario";

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        fish = Path.Combine(path, caminho2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                        fish = Path.Combine(path, caminho2);
                    }
                    File.Create(fish);
                }          
                indexi = listaimg.Items.Count;
                listaimg.Items.Add((indexi + 1) + "- " + caminho2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isso acontece provavelmente porque você está tentando criar um diretório usando um recurso utilizado para criar arquivos. Tente utilizar um [recurso adequado](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2) e veja se as coisas funcionarão como o esperado.

Ou, se eu entendi errado: porque você está tentando criar um arquivo, mas não está mencionando que arquivo é este, como você mesmo destacou no endereço acima. O endereço é escrito somente até o ficheiro "temporario" e é interrompido ali. Isso é um erro. É necessário indicar o arquivo

Comment: Obrigada pelo comentário Caio, mas eu não quero criar um diretório mas sim um ficheiro dentro da pasta. O problema é que quando tento fazê-lo, dá-me erro.

Comment: Tente guardar esse ficheiro com um usuário administrador. Ou as vezes pode até ser um problema relacionado ao Windows. Apague a pasta e crie outra com o mesmo nome.

Comment: @Caio de Paula Silva Eu coloquei o meu código, dê uma vista de olhos

Comment: @PedroDuca Eu apaguei a pasta e criei-a de novo, mas continuo com o mesmo erro. Eu sou um utilizador da rede mas colocaram algumas permissões de administrador para eu usar, e estou a correr o Visual Studio como Administrador.

Comment: Sofia, você garante que além do caminho também está especificando o nome do arquivo a ser criado?

Comment: Esse arquivo temporário é um PDF, certo?

Comment: @PedroDuca Não, o arquivo temporário é uma imagem (pode ser PNG, JPG, BMP ou TIFF) para depois converter em PDF. 
Quando dei o exemplo de PDF, é porque também quero fazer a conversão de PDF para imagem, então guardo os ficheiros PDF numa pasta temporária.

Comment: `E:\` é uma unidade em sua máquina ou um mapeamento de rede?

Comment: E: é a unidade da máquina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui corrigir esse erro juntando as dicas de Pedro Duca e de Augusto Vasques, obrigada a ambos!

**EDIT:** Tive que alterar o código pois estava a retirar o conteúdo do ficheiro inicial, agora apenas copia.

Sendo assim, a resposta final será:

```
            foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                // Obtém o caminho completo do arquivo
                string caminhoCompleto = file;
                caminho2 = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
                caminhotb2.Text = caminhoCompleto;
                string StartDirectory = caminhoCompleto;
                string EndDirectory = @"C:\temporario";

                using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(EndDirectory + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
                    {
                        SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
                    }
                }
                indexi = listabmp.Items.Count;
                listabmp.Items.Add((indexi + 1) + "- " + caminho2);
            }
```

O código foi retirado daqui [LINK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Marque sua resposta como a solução da pergunta.

Comment: Só poderei aceitar como solução dois dias após publicar a resposta. Por isso, amanhã marcarei

Comment: Descobri que esse código acima apaga o conteúdo dentro do ficheiro... Não aconselho a usarem!

Comment: Ele sobrescreve o arquivo que tem o mesmo nome, certo ?

Comment: Certo, mas sem algum conteúdo. Ele está a subscrever o arquivo certo? Em vez de criar um novo noutra localização

Comment: No caso de não ter nenhum conteúdo a principio ele criara o arquivo com o File.Create(). O ideal seria ter um tratamento para caso não tenha o arquivo ele criar, igual já havia feito no código da pergunta

Answer (score 2):

São três os seus problema:

## Primeiro problema:

Você está tentando criar um arquivo quando a permissão que você concedeu ao seu `FileStream` é suficiente só para leitura. Mude o `FileMode` e o `FileAccess` deforma a se adequarem as suas necessidades.

## Segundo Problema:

Ao tentar solucionar o primeiro problema você criou uma variável `path` de testes que fixou o caminho para o `FlieStream` em um diretório que não exite e esqueceu de voltar a variável original que é `caminhotb2.Text`.

## Terceiro problema:

Você não precisa da linha `File.Create(fish);` pois o `FileStream` já criou seu arquivo.

Tente isso:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(caminhotb2.Text, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

e comente ou apague a linha `File.Create(fish);`

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, mas continua a dar erro... De facto esse podia ser um dos meus erros de código, mas penso que seja algo diferente.

Comment: @SofiaRodrigues fiz uma modificação na resposta onde corrigi e testei a solução. Mantive os mesmos objetos do seu código, mas aconselho usar um `SaveFileDialog` ao invés de um `OpenFileDialog`

Comment: O problema de utilizar o `SaveFileDialog` é que, assim, em vez de abrir ficheiros para depois, em segundo plano, serem guardados na pasta, irei guardar ficheiros que ainda nem existem no contexto do programa... Mas de resto, o erro desapareceu!

Comment: Muito obrigada Augusto Vasques. Funciona, mas continuo sem conseguir guardar o ficheiro na pasta... Alterei o `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` para `FileMode.Create` apenas, e continua sem guardar

Comment: Use o método [`Write`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.write?view=netframework-4.7.2) do `FileStream`

Comment: Já resolvi, publiquei a resposta. Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Tente especificar a extensão do arquivo

Por exemplo:

```
string caminho2 ="E:\\temporario.png";
```

Comment: Provavelmente eu expressei-me mal, mas tentarei explicar o que eu pretendo. O diretório da pasta onde eu quero guardar o arquivo é "E:\temporario", o nome do arquivo e a extensão não são sempre as mesmas, então não posso definir o caminho com esse nome e com essa extensão pois ambos podem variar.

Comment: Dai como varia a extensão, você pode fazer para que ele reconheça a extensão com o Path.GetExtension(E:\);

Comment: Então teria que fazer algo do género
`string caminho2 = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
string ex = Path.GetExtension(caminho2);
string path = @"E:\\temporario";
fish = Path.Combine(path, caminho2, ex); 
File.Create(fish);` ??

Comment: Isso, certinho!

Comment: Se eu fizer dessa maneira, dá-me o erro `'Could not find a part of the path 'E:\temporario\sol.jpg\.jpg'.'` pois ao juntar a extensão a um ficheiro cujo nome já contém a extensão, dá esse erro pois adiciona a extensão como se fosse um diretório.

Comment: Já resolvi o problema, publiquei a resposta. Obrigada

Comment: Agora entendi, quando você juntava as strings o "caminho2" já possuía a extensão